# Git push "unmanaged" changes

Tags: git, git-merge

a while ago, when very new to git, I did something dumb.

Specifically, I took a copy of a project using the "download zipfile" option, and made a bunch of changes to it locally. So, the whole directory is essentially unmanaged in git's terms. There are no .git type directories or files, (except the .gitignore that came in the zipfile).

Now, of course, I need to put my changes back into the repository.

What's the best way to go about this? One saving grace is that there have been no changes by anyone (not by me, nor by anyone else) in the meantime.

The only thing that I can think of would be to do a proper "git clone" on the project, then diff each file by hand, copy into place the ones that changed, then do a normal push on it. But that seems like it would be hard work, time consuming, and error prone. I suspect the system has an easy way to address this foolishness on my part?

Cheers,
Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just clone and copy your modified project to the clone in its entirety.  Let git worry about figuring out which relevant files have changed; it's good at that. Commit and push as desired.

(This assumes that the folder layout of the project in the zip file matches that in the git repository.)

Answer (score 0):

Since there's been no changes since the zipfile was generated, that makes things simpler.  There's two ways to do this.  The first is good for generally dealing with the "I made edits to a release and now I don't know what I did" problem regardless of having access to version control.

1. Unpack the original archive again in a different location.
2. `diff -r original devel > my.patch` to get a patch file.
3. `git clone` the repository.
4. `patch -p1 < /path/to/my.patch`.
5. `git add -A .` to add all the changes (including deleted files)
6. `git commit`.

Another way, which I prefer when git is involved, is to...

1. `git clone` the repository.
2. Delete all the files (except the .git directory).
3. Copy all the files from the archive directory where you did your development.
4. `git add -A .` to add all your changes (including deleted files).
5. `git commit`.